Where do I insert the MathJax script so that it renders on GitHub pages when I use Jekyll?
I am trying to integrate MathJax for a math site I am building using Github Pages and Jekyll, and no matter what I try to do, it does not render in LaTeX, even when I build locally. I always end up getting for example, "\(x)\" instead of a LaTeX x.
I have tried to paste in the MathJax javascript from their site
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

The problem is, no matter where I paste it, it does not render. I have tried to copy the base.html file from _layouts and paste it in this file, but to no avail. I have also tried to put it into the head.html from _includes, but it still does not work. I have also made sure to put markdown: kramdown and mathjax: true based on something I have read online. I could really use some help, I have spent hours on this and I am extremely new to web design (and only really want a place to publish some old notes).

I had the same issue and search for another thing I found a way using the config on the question of this issue MathJax does not allow multi-row in-line math on GitHub Pages
Create on _includes the mathjax.html,
_includes
├── contact.html
├── footer.html
├── foundation.html
├── head.html
├── header.html
└── mathjax.html



<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
      equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "all" },
      tagSide: "right"
    },
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
</script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mathjax/MathJax@legacy-v2-develop/unpacked/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>



and include it on head.html


<head>
  {% include mathjax.html %}
</head>



And it works. I hope it helps you.
